# Why is letter "o" with Graphics2D.drawString at font size 101 broken?

Tags: java, fonts, awt, graphics2d

I'd like to draw strings in pngs. I need letters with a height of up to 600 px.

Therefore I tried using Graphics2D.drawString:

```
    String text = "o";
    graphics.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, fontsize));
    graphics.drawString(text, 0, 200);
```

Text with font sizes up to 100 works fine.
Problem: With font size 101 some round characters (like "o") are getting a little angled.

This is reproducable with fonts "Abril_Fatface", "Amatic_SC" and "Cinzel_Decorative" (from google Fonts, e.g. https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Abril+Fatface or https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amatic+SC ; ttf-file downloadable via "select this font" and then "download this section" within the dialog "1 family selected"). With other fonts the strings are drawn OK.

LibreOffice shows the characters round (as expected).

Here is the full code:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.FontFormatException;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    public class CustomFontWriting {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FontFormatException, IOException {
            Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("Amatic_SC.ttf"));
            // Create empty image
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
            graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            // Draw letter "o" with fontsize 101 in an image
            graphics.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 101));
            graphics.drawString("o", 0, 200);
            // Write image to disk
            File output = new File("output.png");
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
        }
    }
```

Expected result: round letter "o".

[image]

Actual result: angled letter "o".

[image]

Comment: looks like whatever's responsible for interpreting the path coordinates is doing it wrong - you might want to ask about this, with a proper [mcve] over on the java bug tracker. Is this with Oracle's JDK or OpenJDK? (or even some third, other version?)

Comment: This happens with OpenJDK 1.8.0_212.

Comment: The example is now a little shorter but still reproduces the problem. With Java SE RE 1.8.0_171-b11 there is no such problem. The example letter is perfectly round.

Comment: then (based on [this](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2015-December/003841.html)) you probably want to file this over on the bugs.java.com, explicitly mentioning that this is for OpenJDK 1.8 (rather than the Oracle JDK). It's possible they're using an older version of harfbuzz/freetype/uniscribe/etc that needs a version bump, or there might even be a bug in the shaping engine they rely on that needs fixing first.

Comment: OK, I filed this over at bugs.java.com and additionally tested with a newer OpenJDK version 1.11.3 (2019-04-16). With OpenJDK 11 my testcase generated successfully round letters. Great. This is the solution I will follow. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use OpenJDK 11 or a later version. See comments at the question.